# Call a method of the child component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a nested child component like this:

```html
<app-main>
    <child-component />
</app-main>
```

My `appMain` component needs to invoke a method on child-component.

How to invoke a method on the child-component?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can get a reference to an element using

```
@ViewChild('childComponent') child;
```

where `childComponent` is a template variable `<some-elem #childComponent`>` or

```
@ViewChild(ComponentType) child;
```

where `ComponentType` is the type of a component or directive and then in `ngAfterViewInit` or an event handlers call `child.someFunc()`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.child);
}
```

See also [get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/217408)

Comment: I think the syntax is `@ViewChild(ComponentName) child;` and according to [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) it is not available until the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook.

Comment: I tried it. When a string is passed it looks up template variables with this name, otherwise a component or directive of the passed type. "Selector" in the docs is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I looked at the [source code for ViewChild](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.0/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata.ts#L1147-L1147), and it says "Supports the same querying parameters as QueryMetadata, except descendants." The [QueryMetadata API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/QueryMetadata-class.html) explains all of the different types of "selectors" that are supported.  (Finding this stuff is such a pain at the moment.)

Answer (score 53):

Parent and child can communicate via data binding.

Example:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    inputs: ['bar'],
    template: `"{{ bar }}" in child, counter  {{ n }}`
})
class ChildComponent{
    constructor () {
        this.n = 0;
    }
    inc () {
        this.n++;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <child-component #f [bar]="bar"></child-component><br>
        <button (click)="f.inc()">call child func</button>
        <button (click)="bar = 'different'">change parent var</button>
    `,
    directives: [ChildComponent]
})
class AppComponent {
    constructor () {
        this.bar = 'parent var';
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/F6S9r1nsLm11Q7TxxQoW?p=preview)

`#f` creates a reference to the child component and can be used in template or passed to function. Data from parent can be passed by `[ ]` binding.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. When i declare a variable like #f - that #f refers to the dom element and when i do f.someMethodCall() i get an error because that method is not defined on that element. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck, if there is no component/directive on the element, the local template variable (e.g., `#f`) refers to the element itself.  Maybe that is your issue.

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck the variable has to be declared before it's usage (you can't put `child-component` from the example as last in the template)

Answer (score 23):

Being a son component

```
@Component({
    // configuration
    template: `{{data}}`,
    // more configuration
})
export class Son {

  data: number = 3;

  constructor() { }

  updateData(data:number) {
    this.data = data;
  }

}
```

Having a father component

```
@Component({
    // configuration
})
export class Parent {
  @ViewChild(Son) mySon: Son;

  incrementSonBy5() {
    this.mySon.updateData(this.mySon.data + 5);
  }
}
```

In the father's template

```
<son></son>
<button (click)="incrementSonBy5()">Increment son by 5</button>
```

This solution only works for one `<son></son>`instance in the parent template. If you have more than one instance only will work in the first one of the template.

Comment: You can just use `@ViewChildren()` to get all of them.

Comment: This tricked me! My intellisense wouldn't pickup the child components methods leading me to believe it wasn't visible! +1

Answer (score 2):

The best way to access a child component is [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildDecorator).

Let's say you have AppMainComponent with a nested ChildComponent from your example.

```
// app-main.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: `
        <child-component />
    `
})

export class AppMainComponent {}
```

You want to invoke a clear method from your ChildComponent.

```
// child.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: '{{ greeting }}'
})

class ChildComponent {
    greeting: String = 'Hello World!';

    clear() {
        this.greeting = null;
    }
}
```

You can accomplish it by importing the ChildComponent class, ViewChild decorator and pass component's class in it as a query. This way, you would have access to the ChildComponent's interface stored in the custom variable. Here is an example:

```
// app-main.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './components/child/child.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: `
        <child-component />
    `
})

class ChildComponent {
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
    child: ChildComponent;

    clearChild() {
        this.child.clear();
    }
}
```

Notice! Child view becomes available only after [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.
>   Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().
>   A component-only hook.

If you want to execute method automatically, you need to do it inside this lifecycle hook.

You can also get a [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) of child components via [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildrenDecorator) decorator.

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './components/child/child.component';

...

@ViewChildren(ChildComponent)
children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

QueryList might be very useful, e.g. you can subscribe for children changes.

It's also possible to create [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) and get access to them via the ViewChild decorator.