# Angular 7: problem with include Component

Tags: javascript, angular

i have this component, already registered in the app.module.ts:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
  providers: [MessageService]
})

export class ModalComponent {

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) { }

  onConfirm() {
  }

  showError(error) {
  }

}
```

but i cannot include this component in another component.
i get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TopbarComponent -> ModalComponent]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TopbarComponent -> ModalComponent]:

this is my TopbarComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { Router } from "@angular/router"
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { JhttpService } from '../jhttp.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topbar',
  templateUrl: './topbar.component.html'
})

export class TopbarComponent {

  user = this.session.get('USER');

  constructor(
    private jhttpService: JhttpService,
    private session: SessionStorageService,
    private router: Router,
    private glob: AppComponent,
    private modal: ModalComponent,
    private app: HomeComponent
  ) { }

  onLogoutButtonClick(event) {
    this.modal.showError('CIAO');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

any suggestion??

Comment: Share the more stacktrace of error.

Comment: ok, i put the stacktrace here: https://pastebin.com/GPzJZ7gU

Answer (score 0):

Remove components from the constructor injection.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { Router } from "@angular/router"
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { JhttpService } from '../jhttp.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topbar',
  templateUrl: './topbar.component.html'
})

export class TopbarComponent {

  user = this.session.get('USER');

  constructor(
    private jhttpService: JhttpService,
    private session: SessionStorageService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  onLogoutButtonClick(event) {
    this.modal.showError('CIAO');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: i put into declarations
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    SubMenuComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,
    ModalComponent
  ],

Comment: Can you check your `TopbarComponent` if you are injecting `ModalComponent` that could be causing the issue.

Comment: i shared the TopbarComponent!

Comment: Updated the answer. It should fix your issue.

Comment: ok, but in this way the function modal.showError, that is in ModalComponent, doesn't work!

Comment: You shouldn't do that way. It looks like your implementation approach is wrong. Better would be if you can provide the stackblitz demo for the same.

Comment: i would like to create a common component with some modal window, and reuse it in all the pages.....is it possible to do something like that??

Comment: Here is the sample demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-example-hdf9gj

Comment: I think you need to add `entryComponents: []` in your app.module and add component you want to use

Comment: Here is the another sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-modal-playground-e81pxz

Answer (score 0):

Do not add Components in the constructor. 
Also make sure that the other `ModalComponent` needs to be part of the module where it's being used. Either import the module of 'ModalComponent' in the module where it is used or add `ModalComponent` to the `declaration` array of the module where you are using it.

Comment: Ok, i have already added the componenti in the moudule,But how can i call that function in that component?.....And, why only the ModalComponent give me that error??

Comment: May be because ModalComponet is not part of the module where it's being used.. you can still call child component method : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013461/call-a-method-of-the-child-component